# Java NoSuchMethodException working with gradle and postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, gradle

Hello i tried to initialize a "simple project" with spring boot using jpa but when starting the app I get the following error (error creating bean with name "entityManagerFactory":

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not initialize PostgreSQLPGObjectJdbcType
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.<clinit>(PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.postgresql.util.PGInterval.getWholeSeconds()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2675) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.<clinit>(PostgreSQLIntervalSecondJdbcType.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

I have java 17 and I am using a gradle project in my gradle file i have the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

I am not sure what is going on.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: It worked after deleting and recreating a project. I was able to do this because I didn't start any development on this but probably not the way to go if you have already worked on the project.

Comment: Did you try a more current driver?

Comment: I tried with the version org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.1 i have the same issue

Comment: Don't know about gradle (though you would presume they were the same) But I had a look on the maven repositories, and indeed the method `org.postgresql.util.PGInterval.getWholeSeconds` does not exist for version `42.1.4`, however I also looked in versions `42.5.*` and the method does exist. Also seems like some vulnerabilities have been fixed.

Comment: I deleted my project, recreated a new one and it worked. Not sure why it was not downloading the version even though I changed it my gradle file